# copy an array from another array on every click from specified index

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, If I have an array a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and b=[]. On every click event, I am passing a number as a parameter.
I need to push the array a[] to array b[] from the next element.
For the first click, I am passing 3 as parameter. Now array b[] will be copied from a[0] to  a[2] which gives me array b=[1,2,3].

When I click second time with passing 2 as parameter, Now array b[] will be copied from a[3] to  a[4] which gives me array b=[1,2,3,4,5].

Desired result:
click(3) = b[1,2,3]
click(2) = b[1,2,3,4,5]

Instead I am getting this
click(3) = b[1,2,3]
click(2) = b[1,2]

```js
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
b = [];

click(e){
for(let i=0; i<=e; i++){
b.push(a[i])
}
```

How to do this? Any thoughts!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Consider revising your question. Confusing

Comment: I can't figure out what is the reason for adding a into the code

Comment: I revised my question. Hope you understand better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the click function gets called you loop from 0 to e. Instead you might want to loop from `b.length` (the next index to copy), e indices further (till `b.length + e`).

Answer (score 0):

The toString is only for formatting the code to show it here in the snippet better.

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let b = [];

function click(n) {
    for (let i=n; i>0; i--) {
        b = b.concat(a.splice(0,i));
        console.log(i + ': ' + '  a: ' + a.toString() + '    b: ' + b.toString());
    }
}

click(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as @JonasWilms suggested. This works.

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let b = [];

function click(n) {
    
    for (var i=b.length; i<= n; i++) {
       b.push(a[i]);
       
    }
    console.log(b);
}
click(1);
click(2);
click(3);
```